# Directing http traffic through an external proxy using istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We are running a bunch of microservices in a istio enabled kubernetes cluster. One of the microservice makes a call to an external service outside of the cluster and I need to route that particular call through the company proxy that is running also external to the cluster.

To explain a bit more, say, I set the HTTP_PROXY in the container and make the curl call to http://external.com the call is success as the call is routed through the proxy but I wanted the istio to do this routing through proxy transparently.

Eg. curl http://external.com from within the container then the istio should automatically route the http call via the company proxy and return back the response

I have created service entries for both external.com and proxy.com to make the call successful

Answer (score -2):

If i understood right what You are looking for is Egress Gateway.

Here is part of tutorial for configuring external HTTPS proxy from Istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/):

> #### Configure traffic to external HTTPS proxy
>
> 1. Define a TCP (not HTTP!) Service Entry for the HTTPS proxy. Although applications use the HTTP CONNECT method to establish connections with HTTPS proxies, you must configure the proxy for TCP traffic, instead of HTTP. Once the connection is established, the proxy simply acts as a TCP tunnel.
>
> ```
>    $ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
>    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
>    kind: ServiceEntry
>    metadata:
>      name: proxy
>    spec:
>      hosts:
>      - my-company-proxy.com # ignored
>      addresses:
>      - $PROXY_IP/32
>      ports:
>      - number: $PROXY_PORT
>        name: tcp
>        protocol: TCP
>      location: MESH_EXTERNAL
>    EOF
> ```
>
> 2. Send a request from the sleep pod in the default namespace. Because the sleep pod has a sidecar, Istio controls its traffic.
>
> ```
>    $ kubectl exec -it $SOURCE_POD -c sleep -- sh -c "HTTPS_PROXY=$PROXY_IP:$PROXY_PORT curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"
>    <title>Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title>
> ```
>
> 3. Check the Istio sidecar proxy’s logs for your request:
>
> ```
>    $ kubectl logs $SOURCE_POD -c istio-proxy
>    [2018-12-07T10:38:02.841Z] "- - -" 0 - 702 87599 92 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "172.30.109.95:3128" outbound|3128||my-company-proxy.com 172.30.230.52:44478 172.30.109.95:3128 172.30.230.52:44476 -
> ```
>
> 4. Check the access log of the proxy for your request:
>
> ```
>    $ kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -n external -l app=squid -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -n external -- tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log
>    1544160065.248    228 172.30.109.89 TCP_TUNNEL/200 87633 CONNECT en.wikipedia.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/91.198.174.192 -
> ```

Check out whole tutorial as it covers setup requirements and also has steps to simulate an external proxy so You can compare if it working as intended.

[istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/)

Comment: In this example curl command explicitly set the HTTPS_PROXY but in my case the curl command will be executed without the proxy setting but still using istio resources I should direct the HTTP traffic via the external proxy.

Comment: @Pradeep Basically we need to define an istio custom resource(ServiceEntry, Gateway or anything else) to direct the traffic to the company proxy without having to set the http_proxy in the container. I have the exact case as you. I haven't found a graceful solution yet. Have you? If you have, would you please share?

Comment: I'm looking for a "transparent" solution with istio as well

Comment: This is a bit old, but... could that help: https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/proxy/ ? idk ... sounds very hacky

Comment: yeah, I'm looking for a "transparent" proxy as well.

Comment: @lyjackal did you find any solution?

Comment: @Froxyz nope, I gave up the search, wasn’t critical for me